# Power set Natural numbers notation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

The "power set" of a set $S$ can be either noted $P(S)$ or $2^S$

However in the case of $$S=\mathbb N$$ I don't know what is the correct second notation.

In [this forum](https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-name-for-the-power-set-of-real-numbers) the user "Jeff Eistein" talks about $2^{\aleph _0}$ but according to the aforementioned definition it should be $2^{\mathbb N}$

Are these two notations equivalent ?

Comment: $\mathcal P(\mathbb N)$ and $2^{\mathbb N}$ are both notations for the powerset of $\mathbb N$, while $2^{\aleph _0}$ is a notation of its cardinality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, they are equivalent, yes. Actually, $\Bbb N$ and $\aleph_0$ are conventionally the exact same set. They are just used to convey different purposes.

$\Bbb N$ is used when you're talking about the natural numbers themselves, their internal ordering, their arithmetic, and so on. $\aleph_0$ is used when you want to talk about the *size* / *cardinality* of the set of natural numbers: the countable infinity.

However, the three objects $2^{\Bbb N}$, $2^{\aleph_0}$ and $P(\Bbb N)$ are all different things, albeit closely related.

- When you write $2^{\Bbb N}$, the operation in question is called set exponentiation. The result is the set of functions $\Bbb N\to2$, where $2$ could denote any 2-element set, but convention is $\{0,1\}$.
- When you write $2^{\aleph_0}$ without any clarification, the operation in question is implicitly assumed to be *cardinal* exponentiation, and it represents the *size* of the set that set exponentiation $2^{\aleph_0}$ yields. Assuming the Axiom of Choice, this is the smallest ordinal number which is in bijection with the set exponentiation $2^{\aleph_0}$. Without Choice I think the exact nature of this object is a lot more fuzzy, but feel free to correct me in the comments.
- The powerset $P(\Bbb N)$ denotes the set of all subsets of $\Bbb N$. It contains the set of odd numbers, the set of factorials, the set of numbers less than 10, and many more, including a *lot* of subsets that defy finite description ("finite description" is, if you want to be strict about it, a logical rabbit hole I don't want to go near, but I will use the term here for simplicity).

What you want to use it for determines which one of these is right for you. In many cases they can be used interchangeably (especially $2^{\Bbb N}$ and $P(\Bbb N)$, see the comment by drhab above for an example, as there is a natural translation between a subset and a function that is either $0$ or $1$), although I will advise you to try to be consistent and not use several of them at once.